# Battery level indication

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging

I have my M2 MacBook Pro connected to the external monitor using USB C cable that is also charging the Mac. During the night, I switch off my Mac and switch the monitor, which disables power to the Mac. When I look into the battery level in the settings in the morning, it says that the computer was charging during night (green lightning sign). Why? Should I worry? I also do have USB hub plugged in.

Comment: Why are you turning off the laptop?

Comment: @MarcWilson Why? Because I was the Windows user for the previous 20 years and its a habbit. So you are saying that I shouldn't switch it off?

Answer (score 1):

**Should I worry?**

No. Your Mac has very sophisticated battery management. You can leave your Mac turned on and connected to the display for months, even years.

There is a setting in System Settings called "Optimized Battery Charging", under Battery > Battery Health. With this on, your Mac will only charge to 80% capacity while it is connected, which may help to extend the useful life of a battery that otherwise would be at 100% for a long time.

I can't remember if that's the default or not.

You can 'force it' to go up to 100%, if you need to take your laptop away and have the full charge.

Comment: Yeah, I have it turned on. My Mac is at 100%, maybe because I've never got it to 80%, however I will try now. The screen somehow didn't upload: imgur.com/a/VYU8Ecm (imgur says it's 18+, don't know why). As you can see it says that it's charging during the night even if I switched the monitor off.

Comment: @Lucek It will only start charging to 80% after about 10 days, once it has established that you are leaving it plugged in most of the time. If it's at 100%, it will simply not charge itself until the level goes down. Honestly: plug it in and use it as you NEED. Don't worry about managing it yourself.

Comment: @benwiggy: "Optimized Battery Charging" is the default. This 80% charging is only invoked when you are using the Mac while it is connected to power.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, for me it took several days before the 80% limit kicked in.